# Is there a way to detect file input closing in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

In Chromium browsers like Opera, Chrome and even IE 11 I can detect file input closing with document.body.onfocus being called, but this doesn't work in Firefox and I can't seem to find any way to do it in Firefox.

Code:

```
const Input = document.createElement('input');

Input.type = 'file';

const ref = {
    files: undefined,
    hasClosed: false,
};

document.body.onfocus = () => ref.hasClosed = true;

Input.onchange = function () {
    ref.files = this.files;
};

document.body.appendChild(Input)

Input.click();

while (ref.files === undefined && !ref.hasClosed) {
    delay(100);
} //checks condition every 100ms
//code to upload the file to my database or not

document.body.removeChild(Input);
```

This works perfectly in chrome etc but in Firefox the onfocus event never fires and the loop never ends...

PS: I can't add a submit button it all has to be done without further input from the user.

Comment: I was able to confirm that in firefox when closing the window of selection of archives the onfocus event in body is executed. Try please on this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s0vpqda8/ . Look at the logs in console

Comment: maybe this comment is relevant in the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus > For onfocus to fire on non-input elements, they must be given the tabindex attribute

Comment: @user615274 if I open your jsfiddle in my freshly installed Firefox browser, open the file explorer and click "cancel" or the X (or even just pick a file) in the corner then the onfocus does not trigger :( There is one at the start when I first click the button, but that doesn't tell me anything about when the user clicked X or cancel.

Comment: I do not understand why you are getting a different experience. Did you try this code in your local, creating a file in your file system and trying

Comment: @user615274 Maybe you have extensions/addons that changes the behaviour? I downloaded and installed Firefox just to see if my code would run on it, so it's as vanilla as it gets